# CSS full screen background image size

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS. Just learnt some basic stuff. Hope someone can give me some help and suggestions on this headache issue.

I am working on a webpage that requires a full screen background image. I am now using "height: 100%" on both selectors: html and the section that contains the background. It looks good when I resize the browser's width, but when I resize my browser's height, the background's height collapse too. I guess what I want to accomplish is:

1. when the browser window is maximized on any screen size, the background is full screen without horizontal scroll bar.
2. when the browser window gets a small width, the background image will always centers in the background.
3. when the browser window gets a small height, don't collapse the height and show the vertical scroll bar. Because I got some text on the background. I don't want the text to go to the other section.

And also please give some suggestions on how I can develop a webpage that is friendly to any screen size and any resizing actions on any screen. Any package? any tool?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this css code.

```
body, 
 html{
min-height:100%; 
} 
body {
background-image:url(Beautiful-White-Horse.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can get more info about how this works here: 
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 2):

Use the following CSS code below on the `body` element if you want it to cover the whole page:

```
body {
    background: url(path/to.image.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will work for all browsers. replace the url with the web address or file location on your machine for the image. Quotes are not needed

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the following codes into your External Stylesheet :

```
 html{background:url(folder_name/file_name.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size:cover;
 -moz-background-size:cover;
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
 -ms-background-size:cover;
 -o-background-size:cover;
```